# API is authorized without the Authorization Headers in Request using Identity Server 4 and .net core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am making the API call after the successfully login through Identity server from my `vue application` (SPA).

Firstly i was adding the Access token in the Header and it was Authorize but i was not getting the claim. [Which i have the separate Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197603/identity-server-4-claims-empty-on-api), and now i tried by removing the access token from the header during API call the application is still being Authorized.

I don't understand how i should solve the problem.

```
service.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  return authService
    .getToken()
    .then(tokenResponse => {
      app.$Progress.start();
      //config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokenResponse}`; removed Token
      return Promise.resolve(config);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      app.prototype.$Progress.fail();
      alert("error");
    });
});
```

**Oidc Client Manager**

```
export default {
    authority: "https://localhost:44305",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: `${domain}/authredirect`,
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope:"openid profile email api1 role",
    post_logout_redirect_uri : `${domain}`,
    silent_redirect_uri: `${domain}/silent`,
}
```

**Identity Server Client Configuration**

```
new Client

    {
        ClientId = "js",
        ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
        RedirectUris =            new List<string> {"http://localhost:8080/silent","http://localhost:8080/authredirect"},
        PostLogoutRedirectUris =   { "http://localhost:8080" },
        AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:8080" },

        AllowedScopes =
        {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
             IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
            "api1",
            "role"
        }
    }
```

**API Configure Services**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters();

    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
        options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });

    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<Guid>>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // register the repository
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));

    services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters();
}
```

I have added the Project on Github. Please suggest me something.
[Link for Project not available currently, i will add again](https://github.com/aakashbashyal21/VueJsIndentiyServer4)

[image: Image showing my Controller with [Authorize] attribute and debugging on the value for User.Identity]

Comment: Do you have any cookies in play in your API app?

Comment: No i am not managing any cookies by  myself.

Comment: Do you definitely have the [Authorize] attribute on your API controller/actions? What does User.Identity return inside you API actions?

Comment: Yeah i have the [Authorize] attribute on my actions. and i User.Identity is null.

Comment: @mackie i have attached the screenshot with the `User.Identity`.

Comment: The fact it's hitting your action code with no identity suggests a configuration problem with MVC. What does your pipeline look like in Configure()?

Comment: https://github.com/aakashbashyal21/VueJsIndentiyServer4/blob/master/IdentityServer/Veritty.Admin/Startup.cs ... you can see here.

Comment: You may need to specify the scheme name in the Authorize attribute in order to tell it to use "Bearer"

Comment: I used `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]`. Still it is authorized.

Comment: Try looking at the logs, they should output debug and info messages about what it's doing in the auth pipeline

Comment: yeah I was missing the 'DefaultChallengeScheme'. I have added the answer on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solved the problems on this.

I was missing the `DefaultChallengeScheme` on my API ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.Authority = "https://localhost:44305";
  options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
  options.ApiName = "api1";
});
```